# What is the average and variation of $20$ dices?

Tags: probability, dice

If I roll a dice the average is

$E(X) = (1+2+3+4+5+6)/6 = 7/2$

and

$$E(X^2) = (1+4+9+16+25+36)/6 = 91/6$$

$$VAR(x) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2 = 91/6 - 49/4 = 35/12$$

**Now the question is: How I can find the average and variation of $20$ dice rolls?**

Comment: The average and variance (not variation) of 20 rolls is 20 times the average and variance of one roll.  The "standard deviation" (the square root of the variance) of 20 rolls is the square root of 20 times the standard deviation for one roll.     By the way, "dice" is already plural.  It is the plural of "die".  You roll one **die** or 20 **dice**.

Comment: @user247327 Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a strange word in English: singular **die**, plural **dice**.  So you should ask about **20 dice**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let X1,X2,...X20 be the result of your 20 rolls.

You want to calculate $E(\sum_{i=1}^{20}{X_i})$ and $Var(\sum_{i=1}^{20}{X_i})$

$E(\sum_{i=1}^{20}{X_i})=\sum _{i=1}^{20}E(X_i)=20\times \frac{7}{2}=70$

$Var(\sum_{i=1}^{20}{X_i})=\sum _{i=1}^{20}Var(X_i)=20\times \frac{35}{12}=\frac{175}{3}$